# PHP script permission problems

Tags: linux, php, permissions

I have a PHP script that attempts to create a file with fopen. Running it however, yields an error stating it doesn't have the right permissions to create the file. I have PHP running under Apache on Ubuntu. How can I grant it permission to edit files in /var/www?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chown -R www-data /var/www
chmod u+w /var/www
```

It would probably be a good idea to narrow this permissions change down to whatever specific directory you need to have files written to.

Comment: Okay, it's just one subfolder of /var/www. Thanks!